# PHP splitting up classes

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and trying to figure out how to logically split up my classes. Here is the very basic setup.

1. index.php -- Top page. When login button is pressed, it calls an external authentication server.
2. callback.php -- Authentication server sends call back here. I store the user's login name.
3. game.php -- this is where I have a web game that makes a POST request to callback.php

Here is what I thought is "correct" practice from other OO languages.

1. I'd like to get the data received in callback.php and store it somewhere else (data.php). The only way I can figure out how to do this is to use a session in callback.php and read it in data.php. Is there a better way to do this or should I keep the data in callback.php (and make the POST request to callback.php instead of data.php)?
2. After the callback.php gets the data from the authentication server, I use a redirect to go to game.php. If the user goes straight to game.php and isn't logged in, I also use a redirect. Is there a better way?

`header("Location: http://www.mypage.com/game.php");`

I'm happy to post any code but I'm guessing it's not necessary for these types of questions. Let me know and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of OO programing to keep code as module as possible while bundling relative modules together.

Example:
  User Object - contains all code relative to users
  Game Object - contains all code relative to games

It is still very likely that you will have code that doesn't belong to a specific object, but more to a particular set of actions. However, OO programming can still be applied even to these.

Example:
  Action page: contains all code relative to dealing with a specific group type of actions (Like handling all the actions/callbacks from a specific frontend page).

That being said, your initial statement of separating into the 3 different files is fine.

I'm assuming the index.php is the front facing said that the user interacts with, so separating that from the backend process or controller is good. It would be better to use an require_once("data.php") versus sending the data over the network again and this way you can save the data to that instance and access it without having to use session variables. I can process the data however you want, and once you get the desired results you can do your header() redirect.

Comment: Thank you! So redirects are the correct way to switch pages and using require_once and storing the data in a separate class is good practice.